# cudaMallocManaged and cudaDeviceSynchronize()

Tags: cuda

I have the following two mostly identical example codes. **code1.cu** use `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy` to handling device/host variable value exchange.

The **code2.cu** use `cudaMallocManaged` and thus `cudaMemcpy` is not needed. When cudaMallocManaged is used, I have to include  `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` to get the correct results, while for the one with cudaMalloc, this is not needed. I would appreciate some hint on why this is happening

**code2.cu**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
//

using namespace std;


// Kernel function to do nested loops
__global__
void add(int max_x, int max_y, float *tot, float *x, float *y)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if(i < max_x && j<max_y) {
        atomicAdd(tot, x[i] + y[j]);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int Nx = 1<<15;
    int Ny = 1<<15;
    float *d_x = NULL, *d_y = NULL;
    float *d_tot = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_x, sizeof(float)*Nx);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_y, sizeof(float)*Ny);
    cudaMallocManaged((void **)&d_tot, sizeof(float));

    // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
    vector<float> vx;
    vector<float> vy;

    // initialize x and y arrays on the host
    for (int i = 0; i < Nx; i++)
        vx.push_back(i);

    for (int i = 0; i < Ny; i++)
        vy.push_back(i*10);

    //
    float tot = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<vx.size(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<vy.size(); j++)
            tot += vx[i] + vy[j];

    cout<<"CPU: tot: "<<tot<<endl;


    //
    cudaMemcpy(d_x, vx.data(), vx.size()*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_y, vy.data(), vy.size()*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //
    int blockSize;   // The launch configurator returned block size
    int minGridSize; // The minimum grid size needed to achieve the
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize( &minGridSize, &blockSize, add, 0, Nx+Ny);

    //.. bx*by can not go beyond the blockSize, or hardware limit, which is 1024;
    //.. bx*bx = blockSize && bx/by=Nx/Ny, solve the equation
    int bx = sqrt(blockSize*Nx/(float)Ny);
    int by = bx*Ny/(float)Nx;
    dim3 blockSize_3D(bx, by);
    dim3 gridSize_3D((Nx+bx-1)/bx, (Ny+by+1)/by);

    cout<<"blockSize: "<<blockSize<<endl;
    cout<<"bx: "<<bx<<" by: "<<by<<" gx: "<<gridSize_3D.x<<" gy: "<<gridSize_3D.y<<endl;

    // calculate theoretical occupancy
    int maxActiveBlocks;
    cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor( &maxActiveBlocks, add, blockSize, 0);

    int device;
    cudaDeviceProp props;
    cudaGetDevice(&device);
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&props, device);

    float occupancy = (maxActiveBlocks * blockSize / props.warpSize) /
        (float)(props.maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor /
                props.warpSize);

    printf("Launched blocks of size %d. Theoretical occupancy: %f\n",
            blockSize, occupancy);


    // Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
    tot = 0;
    add<<<gridSize_3D, blockSize_3D>>>(Nx, Ny, d_tot, d_x, d_y);

    // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
    //cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    tot =*d_tot;
    //

    //
    cout<<" GPU: tot: "<<tot<<endl;
    // Free memory
    cudaFree(d_x);
    cudaFree(d_y);
    cudaFree(d_tot);

    return 0;
}
```

**code1.cu**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
//
using namespace std;


// Kernel function to do nested loops
__global__
void add(int max_x, int max_y, float *tot, float *x, float *y)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if(i < max_x && j<max_y) {
        atomicAdd(tot, x[i] + y[j]);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int Nx = 1<<15;
    int Ny = 1<<15;
    float *d_x = NULL, *d_y = NULL;
    float *d_tot = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_x, sizeof(float)*Nx);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_y, sizeof(float)*Ny);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_tot, sizeof(float));

    // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
    vector<float> vx;
    vector<float> vy;

    // initialize x and y arrays on the host
    for (int i = 0; i < Nx; i++)
        vx.push_back(i);

    for (int i = 0; i < Ny; i++)
        vy.push_back(i*10);

    //
    float tot = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<vx.size(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<vy.size(); j++)
            tot += vx[i] + vy[j];

    cout<<"CPU: tot: "<<tot<<endl;


    //
    cudaMemcpy(d_x, vx.data(), vx.size()*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_y, vy.data(), vy.size()*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    //
    int blockSize;   // The launch configurator returned block size
    int minGridSize; // The minimum grid size needed to achieve the
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize( &minGridSize, &blockSize, add, 0, Nx+Ny);

    //.. bx*by can not go beyond the blockSize, or hardware limit, which is 1024;
    //.. bx*bx = blockSize && bx/by=Nx/Ny, solve the equation
    int bx = sqrt(blockSize*Nx/(float)Ny);
    int by = bx*Ny/(float)Nx;
    dim3 blockSize_3D(bx, by);
    dim3 gridSize_3D((Nx+bx-1)/bx, (Ny+by+1)/by);

    cout<<"blockSize: "<<blockSize<<endl;
    cout<<"bx: "<<bx<<" by: "<<by<<" gx: "<<gridSize_3D.x<<" gy: "<<gridSize_3D.y<<endl;

    // calculate theoretical occupancy
    int maxActiveBlocks;
    cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor( &maxActiveBlocks, add, blockSize, 0);

    int device;
    cudaDeviceProp props;
    cudaGetDevice(&device);
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&props, device);

    float occupancy = (maxActiveBlocks * blockSize / props.warpSize) /
        (float)(props.maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor /
                props.warpSize);

    printf("Launched blocks of size %d. Theoretical occupancy: %f\n",
            blockSize, occupancy);


    // Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
    tot = 0;
    add<<<gridSize_3D, blockSize_3D>>>(Nx, Ny, d_tot, d_x, d_y);

    // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
    //cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //
    cudaMemcpy(&tot, d_tot, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //
    cout<<" GPU: tot: "<<tot<<endl;

    // Free memory
    cudaFree(d_x);
    cudaFree(d_y);
    cudaFree(d_tot);

    return 0;
}


//Code2.cu has the following output:
//
//CPU: tot: 8.79609e+12
//blockSize: 1024
//bx: 32 by: 32 gx: 1024 gy: 1025
//Launched blocks of size 1024. Theoretical occupancy: 1.000000
//GPU: tot: 0
```

After remove the comment on `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`,

> GPU: tot: 8.79609e+12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CUDA kernel launches are asynchronous.  That means that they execute independently of the CPU thread that launched them.

Because of this asynchronous launch, the CUDA kernel is not guaranteed to be finished (or even started) by the time your CPU thread code begins testing the result.

Therefore it is necessary to wait until the GPU kernel is complete, and `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` does exactly that.  `cudaMemcpy` also has a synchronizing effect, so when you remove the `cudaMemcpy` operations, you lose that synchronization, but `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` restores it.

Comment: Thanks for the information. By the way, I was looking for this information on the web but could not make it. Is this documented specifically somewhere?

Comment: The fact that CUDA kernel launches are asynchronous is documented in the [cuda programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution).  When looking for documentation on CUDA, that is a good place to start.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that one need cudaDeviceSynchronize() when not using cudaMemcpy. I recall seeing some post saying cudaMalloc does the synchronization and that's apparently incorrect if I understand you correctly.

Comment: There is no rule or requirement that "one need cudaDeviceSynchronize() when not using cudaMemcpy.", therefore I wouldn't expect to find that documented anywhere.  The characteristics of managed memory, and the asynchronous nature of GPU/CPU execution, are all documented.